# Выполнение системных команд в Linux через php exec

Tags: php, linux, exec

Можно ли получить на выходе функции `exec()` именно текст ошибки, а не код?

Пример :

```
cat: /file_path No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, но для этого используйте функцию [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Она возвращает полный вывод в виде строки, то что вам и нужно.

Вот только нужно ещё дописать `2>&1` для вывода данных в переменную:

```
$output = shell_exec("cat /home 2>&1");

var_dump($output);
```

Вывод будет:

```
string(27) "cat: /home: Is a directory"
```

Comment: не совсем подходит мне,так как функция не возвращает массив с результатом как это делает exec.

Comment: + если использовать конструкцию плана | grep то не возвращает вообще ниче, хотя ошибка о несуществовании файла есть

Comment: @quaresma89 ответ был дан исходя из вопроса